# How to redirect user to a custom page when clicking reload button on a url with parameter

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application that generates a 404 error when the user clicks the browser reload button in a url that has paramenter (generatedid).

http://localhost:4200/abc/generatedid/xyz

That url is generated in abc-routing.module.ts like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':generatedId/xyz', component: XyzComponent, resolve: { my: CarResolver } }
];
```

CarResolver

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CarResolver implements Resolve<Car> {

  constructor(private carService: CarService){  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Car> {

    if(route.params && route.params['generatedId']){
      return this.myService.getMyId(route.params['generatedId'])
      .pipe(shareReplay(),
        catchError(error => {
          this.onError();
          return of({} as Car);
        })
      );

    }

    let car = {} as Car; 
    return of(car);

  }
  
}
```

The problem happens only on urls with parameter. The other ones reload fine.

For the ones with parameter I'd like to, at least, redirect the user to a custom page instead of displaying a 404 message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a typo, we need to set the routing from `generatedid` to `generatedId` at all places

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':generatedId/xyz', component: XyzComponent, resolve: { my: CarResolver } }
];
```

My Theory is that you are making the API call with parameter undefined, which delays the API, and as you know unless the resolver completes the component never loads!

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on the question. In the actual code the name of the parameter is another one and it is camel case both in the routing.module and in the resolver. So they both match. I edited the question to fix that.